# Publish custom maven artifact/package (*.jar) to Azure artifact using azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to push my custom artifact/package (*.jar) to the Azure artifact using maven with the help of Azure DevOps pipeline.
I am using java & building the package using maven.

I can do it by the below script/command in the Azure pipeline.

```
 mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId="com.mypkg" `
-DartifactId="my.artifact" `
-Dversion="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" `
-Dpackaging=jar `
-Dfile="my.artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" `
-DgeneratePom="true" `
-DrepositoryId="$AZURE_FEED_ID" `
-Durl="$AZURE_FEED_URL";
```

I want to know if this can be done by any Azure pipeline task like  "- task: Maven@3"
Because Azure DevOps provides the publish tasks for npm, Gradel, Python etc but not for maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if this can be done by any Azure pipeline task like "- task: Maven@3"

Yes, the maven deploy step can be done via Maven task.

Here is an example:

```
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven pom.xml'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: pom.xml
    goals: 'deploy:deploy-file'
    options: '-DgroupId="com.mypkg"  -DartifactId="my.artifact" -Dversion="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"  -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="my.artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" -DgeneratePom="true" -DrepositoryId="$AZURE_FEED_ID" -Durl="$AZURE_FEED_URL"'
```

The deploy command can be defined at **goals** field and the arguments can be defined at **options** field.

For more info, you can refer to the doc about [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops).